# Compiling error on template method, return is instance from inner class

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a simplified example:

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplate
{
  class Inner {};
  Inner met();
};

template<typename T>
MyTemplate<T>::Inner  MyTemplate<T>::met()
{ }
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'met'
```

I use GCC. It seems the compiler doesn't recognize `MyTemplate<T>::Inner` as a proper class. How can I fix this? I've tried sticking the `typename` keyword here and there to no avail. Right now, the only way I can manage to compile this is to inline the method definition in the class declaration, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: `typename MyTemplate<T>::Inner MyTemplate<T>::met()` and my GCC 4.6 is happy with your code. Which version of GCC are you using?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Clang reports the following:

```
error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name
'MyTemplate<T>::Inner' MyTemplate<T>::Inner  MyTemplate<T>::met()
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ typename  1 error generated.
```

And placing `typename` in the appropriate place fixes it.

```
template<typename T>
class MyTemplate
{
  class Inner {};
  Inner met();
};

template<typename T>
typename MyTemplate<T>::Inner  MyTemplate<T>::met()
{ }
```

Did you put typename in the correct location?  If so, then this must be a bug in G++.

Comment: Crap… I could swear I had tried that. Thank you (it works)!

Comment: Although that answers the question, it would be nice if you'd give the questioner a hint towards dependent names and why that's relevant.

Comment: @phresnel Thank you for setting me on the trail of some additional googling, it was quite enlightening!

Answer (score 13):

The return type of `MyTemplate::met` is a dependent name, so you need to add the `typename` keyword before it. The following compiles on gcc-4.5.1

```
template<typename T>
struct MyTemplate
{
  class Inner {};
  Inner met();
};

template<typename T>
typename MyTemplate<T>::Inner  MyTemplate<T>::met()
{
  return typename MyTemplate<T>::Inner();
}

int main()
{
  MyTemplate<int> foo;

  MyTemplate<int>::Inner bar = foo.met();
}
```

Comment: Well, it almost compiles.  `met` needs to return a value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `typename` keyword before `MyTemplate<T>::Inner` because `MyTemplate<T>` is a dependent scope.